# Frequency of pulsating DC

Tags: rectifier

If frequency is the concept bound to pure AC waveforms then why is it said that pulsating DC has a frequency?

For example, it's said that the output frequency of the full wave rectifier is double the input frequency.

Why is it said so when a rectifier's input is AC and the output is pulsating DC?

We know that DC has a zero frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If frequency is the concept bound to pure ac waveform then why it's said that pulsating DC has a frequency.

Frequency is a property of any periodic waveform, whether it is a pure sine wave, or periodic pulses.

The frequency of a periodic waveform is the reciprocal of the period.

However, any periodic waveform may be *decomposed* into the sum of pure sinewaves of different frequencies (and phases) plus possibly a DC component. In that sense, one might say that a non-sinewave periodic waveform has *many* frequencies. In that case, the reciprocal of the period is called the *fundamental* frequency.

> For example it's said that the output frequency of the full wave rectifier is double the input frequency.

> Why it's said so when a rectifier's input is ac and the output is pulsating DC.

Because the pulsations are regular. They repeat regularly with a particular period.

> And we know that DC has a zero frequency.

Pure DC, that is a *constant* voltage or current, has no frequency. What you call "pulsating DC", if the pulses are periodic, i.e. recurring regularly, will have a frequency (or frequencies, depending upon one's point of view at the moment).

Comment: Thanks actually I thought that there should must be a waveform reservsing direction to have the concept of frequency related to it but you added to my knowledge that the waveform only needs to be preiodic to have a frequency and the resiprocal of period of a preiodic frequency is called fundamental frequency which is then known as the frequency of the preiodic waveform. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Alex Spend some time with 3Blue1Brown on Youtube. Particularly in the context of Fourier Transforms, winding frequency, etc. He presents pieces of beauty. Truly wonderful stuff. Much will become clearer than they currently are, as a result of time spend with him.